# jQuery Selector Test For All of a ClassType

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table. The table data elements each have a div with a class in them. The div displays a small CSS box, which based on the background color gives the appearance of a light, which turns on or off.

I want to turn the lights on and off individually by clicking on them (at random), but then I need to test when any light is turned off, are all lights now off.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="lightbox lightbox-on">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="lightbox lightbox-off">
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
 </table>
```

In other words, if the most recent click turned off the last "on" light, so that all lightbox-on classes have been removed and replaced with lightbox-off classes, trigger something.

The question goes to testing whether a group of divs all contain the same set of identical classes.

Comment: where is your javascript which toggles the class on/off?  I would, update a variable in there which would update the last off item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JQuery you can do this quite easily with something like this:

```
$(".lightbox").click(function() {

  // Remove the lastturnedon class from all lights
  $(".lightbox").removeClass("lastturnedon");

  if (!$(this).hasClass("lightbox-on")) {
    // Add the the lastturnedon class to the clicked light only if we are turning it on.
    $(this).addClass("lastturnedon");
  }

  // Changing the lights state (on/off).
  $(this).toggleClass("lightbox-on");

  if (!$(".lightbox").hasClass("lightbox-on")) {
    // Alert if now that we turned off this light, all lights are off
    alert("All lights are off");
  }
});
```

Here is an example:
http://codepen.io/nathanfelix/pen/XdVrvo

Answer (score 0):

I think the most direct thing to do is just turn off all of them before adding the on to the one you want to.

```
$('.lightbox').removeClass('lightbox-on');
```

Comment: Lights may be clicked multiple times so that many lights are going on and off wth more than one light on at the same time. The condition that causes the trigger is when they reach a state that all lights are off at the same time.

Comment: So you just want to test if the class doesn't exist:

    `if ( ! ($( ".lightbox-on" ).length) ) { ... }`

Comment: In other words, all divs have the same class at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

After click or toggle, use .length to count the number of visible elements, something like:

```
if ( $('.lightbox-on:visible').length == 1) {
// only 1 lit, do something here
}
```

or

```
if ( $('.lightbox-on:visible').length == 0) {
// they're all off, do something here
}
```